# Retrieve a company's list of all physical assets locations based on its name

Tags: geospatial, scraping

I have a list of ~1500 companies, of which I know only their names and possibly some identifiers such as the ISIN or the Ticker codes. For each of them, I would need to find the addresses of all their assets locations (not only their HQ address). For example let's say that one of the company is Exxon Mobil, I would need to produce a list of all the offices, refineries, extraction sites, ... where Exxon operates. Do you know any services/databases/API that I could use?

I already tried with Google maps APIs (e.g. Places API) but they are not working cause I would need to search for all assets all over the world, and not only in the proximity of a specific place.

Comment: Generally this is not public information. Answer highly depends on the country you are in. What makes you think this is possible? (by the way this should probably be asked on the open data SE)

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible, that is why I'm asking if anyone has any ideas or has already done it in the past. Thanks for the reco, I will post the question there too.